# how to remove slash from url with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

how to redirect trailing slash from URL i want remove slash from end and romove slash between FILENAME

```
url => http://localhost/
url => http://localhost/customer/
url => http://localhost/customer/account///login/
url => http://localhost/customer/account/login///register///
```

And after cleaning url

```
http://localhost
http://localhost/customer
http://localhost/customer/account/login
http://localhost/customer/account/login/register
```

this is code htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

Options -Indexes
Options -MultiViews

# view only www
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
# RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

<Files ~ '^.ht'>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

# remove one slash 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)/+(/[^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)/+(/[^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=302,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

RewriteRule htaccess to always remove trailing slash even directory

Try To Use The Code Below -

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: It was you that did not work code and did not enter any other page

Comment: @amirsharifou sorry didn't got what you said