# .htaccess: Remove '/' from end of url if matches

Tags: .htaccess

I have a directory called `company` and another one called `company?ID=L` (Yes, I know, don't ask me why)...

If I try to visit `domain.com/company?ID=L` I get redirected to `domain.com/company`***/***`?ID=L`

How can I tell .htaccess to accept that pattern, so that I can access the `domain.com/company?ID=L` directory?

Thanks!

Comment: What does this have to do with .htaccess? If you want to use characters that have a special meaning in a URL, as “normal” ones, then you should apply proper URL encoding.

Comment: That worked. Guess I was trying to find a harder solution to a simple problem. Also was considering the SEO implications there. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate to this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/36654531/13378977